# Can you explain me how this array element access works?

Tags: java

```
int index=1;
int[] array = {1,2,3};
System.out.println(array[index=2]);
```

i do not understand this in-bracket instantiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of an assignment expression (`index=2`) is the value that was assigned, so `2` gets assigned to `index`, and then used as the index in `array[...]`, just like this:

```
int index=1;
int[] array = {1,2,3};
index = 2; // ***
System.out.println(array[index]);
// or arguably:
//System.out.println(array[2]);
```

Comment: I understand this. But it seems very strange to me

Comment: @UladzislauDukhamenka please explain clearly what you don't understand, then.

Comment: @UladzislauDukhamenka - I'm guessing you're used to a language that has only assignment *statements* and not assignment *expressions* (various dialects of BASIC, for instance). Most languages with syntax derived from B and C (C, C++, Java, JavaScript, C#, ...), though, have this assignment expression form, and it's quite handy sometimes. For instance, reading lines from a stream until `readLine` returns `null`: `String line; while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) { /* ...use line ... */ }` :-)

Comment: No, I am working as a java developer for a year. I just do not understand the logic of this in-bracket instantiation and its use cases.

Comment: @UladzislauDukhamenka - It's not an instantiation, it's an assignment. The fact it's in brackets just means that's where it was used. One of the key things about expressions is that any expression can be used anywhere an expression is valid. Why did the author do it in this particular case? I don't see any good reason, other than to show that it can be done.